# How to extract one kind of values from a list of object type

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to C#. I want to  fetch data from database and group it( account numbers with their corresponding item numbers ), save it in a list and send it to some other function . In that function, I want to extract only item numbers from that list and send those item numbers one by one as a parameter of stored procedure for further processing(database update).

The issue I am facing is that I am not able to update the database.The control is going to `Console.WriteLine("Failed")`.I believe the issue is in the foreach loop in the UpdatePrice function(Not sure if this is what is causing issue).

**My Effort**

My class ListItems is as below -

```
class ListItem
{
    public string accountNumber { get; set; }

       public List<string> itemNumbers { get; set; }

       
    }
```

I am successfully able to fetch data from the database, group it and send it to `UpdatePrice()` -

```
 accounts = (from result in dt.AsEnumerable() group result by result.Field<string>("accountNumber") into g select new ListItem { accountNumber = g.Key, itemNumbers = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("itemnumber")).ToList() }).ToList();

UpdatePrice(accounts);
```

Now, This is how I am trying to extract items from the List `accounts`

```
private void UpdatePrice(List<ListItem> accounts)
        {

            var items = (from item in accounts
            select item.itemNumbers);
 con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_updateItems";
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@itemnumber";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            con.Open();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {

                param.Value = item.ToString();
                
                cmd.Connection = con;
                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (n > 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Price Updated Successfully");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed");
                
            }
            con.Close();
}
```

The foreach loop here, instead of one item it is taking two items at a time. The `var item` consist if count 2 in one iteration . The Linq which I am using is storing items in a group At index 0, it has 2 items and at index 1, it has 6 items. This is I believe causing the issue. How can I simply store all the items serially in a list ?

**Edit**

I believe if it's the LINQ query that I should change .But how do I get all the item numbers to store serially rather than in groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `UpdatePrice` after your query, `items` contains an `IEnumerable<List<string>>`, so on each iteration `item` will be a `List<string>` not a `string`.

You can flatten the graph using `SelectMany`:

```
var items = accounts.Select(a => a.itemNumbers).SelectMany(i => i);
```